# Multiple CASE WHEN statements only outputing single row

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to create an Oracle query that outputs twenty rows. Each row (name_x) should only have one value outside of col_a1 and col_a2.  Every time I run the query below, I only end up with 1 row. and 'name_1' through 'name_20' result in zeros, but Name_T is published successfully.

```
SELECT col_a1, col_a2, 
Coalesce (max(name_1),0) name_1,
Coalesce (max(name_2),0) name_2,
Name_t
...

FROM(
SELECT 
CASE WHEN b.col_b1 = 'Y' and a.col_a3 = 'X' THEN a.col_a4 ELSE NULL END name_1,
CASE WHEN b.col_b1 = 'Y' and a.col_a3 = 'X2' THEN a.col_a4 ELSE NULL END name_2,
…
CASE WHEN a.col_A3 = 'Z' then a.col_a4 else null name_T
FROM dbA.TbA a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbB.TbB Where X) b
ON a.col_W = b.col_W
)
Group by col_a1, col_a2
```

Okay after reading the comments, I went back and fixed a few errors stemming from the fact that my subquery wasn't working. I was able to publish the subquery correctly for the first time!  I'm now unable to 'GROUP BY col_a1, col_a2' and get the invalid identifier error, which I'm working on now.

Comment: Does the sub-query standalone return the expected result?

Comment: BTW, those are case _expressions_. (The case expression returns a value. The case statement is for conditional execution of code in stored procedures.)

Comment: Are you separating each `case` statement with `,`. I don't see it in your query ? Also, what values does `col_a1 and col_a2` contain.. any example data will be helpful.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for this! I hadn't thought to run the subquery (I'm pretty novice obviously), I saw it wasn't working, but was able to troubleshoot to clear it up.

Comment: @Arihant I forgot to put the commas in my question.  Thanks for pointing it out!  I'm now trying to figure out my inability to group by col_a1 and col_a2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have forgot to add `col_a1, col_a2` in your subquery.

```
SELECT col_a1, col_a2, 
Coalesce (max(name_1),0) name_1,
Coalesce (max(name_2),0) name_2,
Name_t
...

FROM(
SELECT 
col_a1, col_a2,
CASE WHEN b.col_b1 = 'Y' and a.col_a3 = 'X' THEN a.col_a4 ELSE NULL END name_1,
CASE WHEN b.col_b1 = 'Y' and a.col_a3 = 'X2' THEN a.col_a4 ELSE NULL END name_2,
…
CASE WHEN a.col_A3 = 'Z' then a.col_a4 else null name_T
FROM dbA.TbA a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbB.TbB Where X) b
ON a.col_W = b.col_W
)
Group by col_a1, col_a2
```